# How to detect number between underscore ("_")?

Tags: c#, regex

Sorry first, im not good at Regex but anyone can help me ? i have file that named :

> Filename - 01.exe
>
> Filename - 001.exe
>
> Filename - 0001.exe
>
> Filename_01_.exe

I have tried with this Regex

```
(?=.*?)\d{1,4}\b
```

But that just detect 01, 001, 0001 number at Filename - 01.exe, Filename - 001.exe and Filename - 0001.exe, not worked with Filename_01_.exe
Is my Regex is wrong or there Alternative Regex or Method ?

Sorry if my english is not well.

Comment: Note: there's a difference between `\d` and "a number"; `\d` will actually match a wide range of unicode characters that represent numbers; you *might* actually mean `[0-9]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only `01` from this `Trailer ep 01 720p.mp4` example, then use word boundaries,

```
\b[0-9]+\b
```

`\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

And the below regex would match the number which are located in between word boundaries or `_` symbol.

```
(?:_|\b)\K[0-9]+(?=_|\b)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1eW6/3)

Comment: It worked, but doesnt work with Trailer ep_01_720p.mp4

Answer (score 2):

Since there is only one number in the file, how about simply using this:

```
\d+
```

In C#:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"\d+");
string resultString = myRegex.Match(yourString).Value;
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Comment: But how if there 2 or more number at filename ? example Trailer ep 01 720p.mp4 ... how if i want to get only 01 without 720, if i'd use only \d+ it can get both number, actually, it get first number detected but how if 720p and 01 are swapped?